# Better way of scaling a dgr_graph within a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, diagrammer

I'm building a shiny app that is supposed to show a `bupaR` `process_map`, which is kind of working.

Sadly the `process_map()`-function returns a `dgr_graph`-object, which can't be rendered with the `DiagrammeR::renderGrViz()` or `DiagrammeR::renderDiagrammeR()` functions. I found a way to convert it to a `grViz / htmlwidget`-object with `render_graph()`, but this way the graph is not nicely scaled. This is especially bad since I'm dealing with very long linear graphs.

Here is a MWE:

```
# server.R
library(DiagrammeR)
library(bupaR)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    plot <- patients %>%
      process_map(rankdir = "TB",
                  render = FALSE)

    output$diagram <- renderGrViz({
      render_graph(plot)
    })

  }
)
```

```
# ui.R
library(DiagrammeR)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DiagrammeR + shiny"),
  grVizOutput(outputId = "diagram")
))
```

Is there a better way of displaying a `dgr_graph`-object in shiny, that fills out the whole width of the app and not just a post-stamp size in the middle? Ideal would be something adaptive, without the need for a fixed width in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the problem is not the `render_graph`-function on the Server, but rather the default setting of the `renderGrViz`-function in the UI. When you set it to  `grVizOutput(outputId = "diagram", height = "100%")` it works just fine.